# Adding WMTS basemap.at to GeoServer?

Tags: geoserver, wmts

Tried to add "basemap.at" WMTS (Austrian Basemap grey) in GeoServer 2.12.1 as Datastore/Layer.

The preview just shows the image attached.

In QGIS and Leaflet the WMTS works well - the getCapabilities-request shows that the service CRS is epsg:3857. Tried also with setting "use defined CRS" because geoserver shows as native one epsg:4326.

[image]

Comment: What is the datasource of your datasource? To cascade a WMTS service, take a look at http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/data/cascaded/wmts.html - available in GeoServer 2.13(!)

Comment: It's the same with the WMTS data from KAGIS. Did you get it working with oder wmts sources?

Comment: @flox I wish I could comment but I cant. Did you ever get a solution to this. I'm in the exact same spot adnd I can't figure it out. Is it as a result of the fact that GWC has no concept of GeoserverSecuritySubSystem so authorization to GetTile is not successful. Since I'm also not able to Cascade WMTS with Basic Authentication, I had to supply Authkey (luckily I had it working). However, the Layers are still not working. I get the exact same response as yours.

Comment: I had similar problem. Checking result of GetCapabilities helped to solve the problem. GetCapabilities may have some vendor specific options which may "confuse" geoserver.

Comment: does the log file show anything?