# Cascading WTMS from ArcGIS Server in GeoServer?

Tags: geoserver, arcgis-server, arcgis-10.5, wmts

I am having problems cascading WTMS from ArcGIS (v10.5) in GeoServer (v2.13). I can create the store and publish a layer but when I go to Layer Preview I get a screen like the below. The same layer is visible in QGIS, I just cannot seem to get it to cascade in GeoServer.

Looking at the GeoServer log (extract below) ArcGIS seems to be issuing a 400 'bad request' to the tile request.

```
2018-05-09 16:35:27,922 ERROR [geotools.tile] - 
Failed to load image: https://****-****-esr73/arcgis/rest/services/Basemaps/Locate/MapServer/WMTS?request=getTile&tilematrixset=default028mm&TileRow=80&service=WMTS&format=image%2Fpng&style=&TileCol=122&version=1.0.0&layer=Basemaps_Locate&TileMatrix=8&

java.io.IOException: Connection returned code 400
```

There reference to a very similar issue in another post but the answer is not very specific
[Adding WMTS basemap.at to GeoServer?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/265086/geoserver-2-12-1-problems-with-wmts-basemap-at)

[image]

ArcGIS WMTS Capabilities

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
<Capabilities xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wmts/1.0" xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wmts/1.0 http://schemas.opengis.net/wmts/1.0/wmtsGetCapabilities_response.xsd"
    version="1.0.0">
    <!--  Service Identification -->
    <ows:ServiceIdentification>
        <ows:Title>Basemaps_Locate</ows:Title>
        <ows:ServiceType>OGC WMTS</ows:ServiceType>
        <ows:ServiceTypeVersion>1.0.0</ows:ServiceTypeVersion>
    </ows:ServiceIdentification>
    <!--  Operations Metadata -->
    <ows:OperationsMetadata>
        <ows:Operation name="GetCapabilities">
            <ows:DCP>
                <ows:HTTP>
                    <ows:Get
                        xlink:href="http://esri-server/arcgis/rest/services/Basemaps/Locate/MapServer/WMTS/1.0.0/WMTSCapabilities.xml">
                        <ows:Constraint name="GetEncoding">
                            <ows:AllowedValues>
                                <ows:Value>RESTful</ows:Value>
                            </ows:AllowedValues>
                        </ows:Constraint>
                    </ows:Get>
                    <!--  add KVP binding in 10.1 -->
                    <ows:Get
                        xlink:href="http://esri-server/arcgis/rest/services/Basemaps/Locate/MapServer/WMTS?">
                        <ows:Constraint name="GetEncoding">
                            <ows:AllowedValues>
                                <ows:Value>KVP</ows:Value>
                            </ows:AllowedValues>
                        </ows:Constraint>
                    </ows:Get>
                </ows:HTTP>
            </ows:DCP>
        </ows:Operation>
        <ows:Operation name="GetTile">
            <ows:DCP>
                <ows:HTTP>
                    <ows:Get
                        xlink:href="http://esri-server/arcgis/rest/services/Basemaps/Locate/MapServer/WMTS/tile/1.0.0/">
                        <ows:Constraint name="GetEncoding">
                            <ows:AllowedValues>
                                <ows:Value>RESTful</ows:Value>
                            </ows:AllowedValues>
                        </ows:Constraint>
                    </ows:Get>
                    <ows:Get
                        xlink:href="http://esri-server/arcgis/rest/services/Basemaps/Locate/MapServer/WMTS?">
                        <ows:Constraint name="GetEncoding">
                            <ows:AllowedValues>
                                <ows:Value>KVP</ows:Value>
                            </ows:AllowedValues>
                        </ows:Constraint>
                    </ows:Get>
                </ows:HTTP>
            </ows:DCP>
        </ows:Operation>
    </ows:OperationsMetadata>
    <Contents>
        <!-- Layer -->
        <Layer>
            <ows:Title>Basemaps_Locate</ows:Title>
            <ows:Identifier>Basemaps_Locate</ows:Identifier>
            <ows:BoundingBox crs="urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::3857">
                <ows:LowerCorner>-996015.8687000014 7154565.521499999</ows:LowerCorner>
                <ows:UpperCorner>-574291.5690000014 7437283.814607762</ows:UpperCorner>
            </ows:BoundingBox>
            <ows:WGS84BoundingBox crs="urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:2:84">
                <ows:LowerCorner>-8.947362780787937 53.917596728660605</ows:LowerCorner>
                <ows:UpperCorner>-5.1589489397368204 55.386712748556874</ows:UpperCorner>
            </ows:WGS84BoundingBox>
            <Style isDefault="true">
                <ows:Title>Default Style</ows:Title>
                <ows:Identifier>default</ows:Identifier>
            </Style>
            <Format>image/jpgpng</Format>
            <TileMatrixSetLink>
                <TileMatrixSet>default028mm</TileMatrixSet>
            </TileMatrixSetLink>
            <TileMatrixSetLink>
                <!-- Only show this TileMatrixSet if the tiling scheme is compliant to Google Maps (and that happens with tile width = 256 px) -->
                <TileMatrixSet>GoogleMapsCompatible</TileMatrixSet>
            </TileMatrixSetLink>
            <ResourceURL format="image/jpgpng" resourceType="tile"
                template="http://esri-server/arcgis/rest/services/Basemaps/Locate/MapServer/WMTS/tile/1.0.0/Basemaps_Locate/{Style}/{TileMatrixSet}/{TileMatrix}/{TileRow}/{TileCol}"
            />
        </Layer>
        <!-- TileMatrixSet -->
        <TileMatrixSet>
            <ows:Title>TileMatrix using 0.28mm</ows:Title>
            <ows:Abstract>The tile matrix set that has scale values calculated based on the dpi
                defined by OGC specification (dpi assumes 0.28mm as the physical distance of a
                pixel).</ows:Abstract>
            <ows:Identifier>default028mm</ows:Identifier>
            <ows:SupportedCRS>urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::3857</ows:SupportedCRS>
            <TileMatrix>
                <ows:Identifier>0</ows:Identifier>
                <ScaleDenominator>5.590822640285016E8</ScaleDenominator>
                <TopLeftCorner>-2.0037508342787E7 2.0037508342787E7</TopLeftCorner>
                <TileWidth>256</TileWidth>
                <TileHeight>256</TileHeight>
                <MatrixWidth>1</MatrixWidth>
                <MatrixHeight>1</MatrixHeight>
            </TileMatrix>
            <TileMatrix>
                <ows:Identifier>1</ows:Identifier>
                <ScaleDenominator>2.7954113201425034E8</ScaleDenominator>
                <TopLeftCorner>-2.0037508342787E7 2.0037508342787E7</TopLeftCorner>
                <TileWidth>256</TileWidth>
                <TileHeight>256</TileHeight>
                <MatrixWidth>1</MatrixWidth>
                <MatrixHeight>1</MatrixHeight>
            </TileMatrix>
            <TileMatrix>
                <ows:Identifier>2</ows:Identifier>
                <ScaleDenominator>1.3977056600712562E8</ScaleDenominator>
                <TopLeftCorner>-2.0037508342787E7 2.0037508342787E7</TopLeftCorner>
                <TileWidth>256</TileWidth>
                <TileHeight>256</TileHeight>
                <MatrixWidth>2</MatrixWidth>
                <MatrixHeight>2</MatrixHeight>
            </TileMatrix>
            <TileMatrix>
                <ows:Identifier>3</ows:Identifier>
                <ScaleDenominator>6.988528300356235E7</ScaleDenominator>
                <TopLeftCorner>-2.0037508342787E7 2.0037508342787E7</TopLeftCorner>
                <TileWidth>256</TileWidth>
                <TileHeight>256</TileHeight>
                <MatrixWidth>4</MatrixWidth>
                <MatrixHeight>3</MatrixHeight>
            </TileMatrix>
            <TileMatrix>
                <ows:Identifier>4</ows:Identifier>
                <ScaleDenominator>3.494264150178117E7</ScaleDenominator>
                <TopLeftCorner>-2.0037508342787E7 2.0037508342787E7</TopLeftCorner>
                <TileWidth>256</TileWidth>
                <TileHeight>256</TileHeight>
                <MatrixWidth>8</MatrixWidth>
                <MatrixHeight>6</MatrixHeight>
            </TileMatrix>
            <TileMatrix>
                <ows:Identifier>5</ows:Identifier>
                <ScaleDenominator>1.7471320750890587E7</ScaleDenominator>
                <TopLeftCorner>-2.0037508342787E7 2.0037508342787E7</TopLeftCorner>
                <TileWidth>256</TileWidth>
                <TileHeight>256</TileHeight>
                <MatrixWidth>16</MatrixWidth>
                <MatrixHeight>11</MatrixHeight>
            </TileMatrix>
            <TileMatrix>
                <ows:Identifier>6</ows:Identifier>
                <ScaleDenominator>8735660.375445293</ScaleDenominator>
                <TopLeftCorner>-2.0037508342787E7 2.0037508342787E7</TopLeftCorner>
                <TileWidth>256</TileWidth>
                <TileHeight>256</TileHeight>
                <MatrixWidth>32</MatrixWidth>
                <MatrixHeight>21</MatrixHeight>
            </TileMatrix>
            <TileMatrix>
                <ows:Identifier>7</ows:Identifier>
                <ScaleDenominator>4367830.187722647</ScaleDenominator>
                <TopLeftCorner>-2.0037508342787E7 2.0037508342787E7</TopLeftCorner>
                <TileWidth>256</TileWidth>
                <TileHeight>256</TileHeight>
                <MatrixWidth>63</MatrixWidth>
                <MatrixHeight>42</MatrixHeight>
            </TileMatrix>
            <TileMatrix>
                <ows:Identifier>8</ows:Identifier>
                <ScaleDenominator>2183915.0938617955</ScaleDenominator>
                <TopLeftCorner>-2.0037508342787E7 2.0037508342787E7</TopLeftCorner>
                <TileWidth>256</TileWidth>
                <TileHeight>256</TileHeight>
                <MatrixWidth>125</MatrixWidth>
                <MatrixHeight>83</MatrixHeight>
            </TileMatrix>
            <TileMatrix>
                <ows:Identifier>9</ows:Identifier>
                <ScaleDenominator>1091957.5469304253</ScaleDenominator>
                <TopLeftCorner>-2.0037508342787E7 2.0037508342787E7</TopLeftCorner>
                <TileWidth>256</TileWidth>
                <TileHeight>256</TileHeight>
                <MatrixWidth>249</MatrixWidth>
                <MatrixHeight>165</MatrixHeight>
            </TileMatrix>
            <TileMatrix>
                <ows:Identifier>10</ows:Identifier>
                <ScaleDenominator>545978.7734656851</ScaleDenominator>
                <TopLeftCorner>-2.0037508342787E7 2.0037508342787E7</TopLeftCorner>
                <TileWidth>256</TileWidth>
                <TileHeight>256</TileHeight>
                <MatrixWidth>498</MatrixWidth>
                <MatrixHeight>330</MatrixHeight>
            </TileMatrix>
            <TileMatrix>
                <ows:Identifier>11</ows:Identifier>
                <ScaleDenominator>272989.38673237007</ScaleDenominator>
                <TopLeftCorner>-2.0037508342787E7 2.0037508342787E7</TopLeftCorner>
                <TileWidth>256</TileWidth>
                <TileHeight>256</TileHeight>
                <MatrixWidth>995</MatrixWidth>
                <MatrixHeight>659</MatrixHeight>
            </TileMatrix>
            <TileMatrix>
                <ows:Identifier>12</ows:Identifier>
                <ScaleDenominator>136494.69336618503</ScaleDenominator>
                <TopLeftCorner>-2.0037508342787E7 2.0037508342787E7</TopLeftCorner>
                <TileWidth>256</TileWidth>
                <TileHeight>256</TileHeight>
                <MatrixWidth>1990</MatrixWidth>
                <MatrixHeight>1317</MatrixHeight>
            </TileMatrix>
            <TileMatrix>
                <ows:Identifier>13</ows:Identifier>
                <ScaleDenominator>68247.34668309252</ScaleDenominator>
                <TopLeftCorner>-2.0037508342787E7 2.0037508342787E7</TopLeftCorner>
                <TileWidth>256</TileWidth>
                <TileHeight>256</TileHeight>
                <MatrixWidth>3979</MatrixWidth>
                <MatrixHeight>2634</MatrixHeight>
            </TileMatrix>
            <TileMatrix>
                <ows:Identifier>14</ows:Identifier>
                <ScaleDenominator>34123.67334154626</ScaleDenominator>
                <TopLeftCorner>-2.0037508342787E7 2.0037508342787E7</TopLeftCorner>
                <TileWidth>256</TileWidth>
                <TileHeight>256</TileHeight>
                <MatrixWidth>7958</MatrixWidth>
                <MatrixHeight>5267</MatrixHeight>
            </TileMatrix>
            <TileMatrix>
                <ows:Identifier>15</ows:Identifier>
                <ScaleDenominator>17061.836671245605</ScaleDenominator>
                <TopLeftCorner>-2.0037508342787E7 2.0037508342787E7</TopLeftCorner>
                <TileWidth>256</TileWidth>
                <TileHeight>256</TileHeight>
                <MatrixWidth>15915</MatrixWidth>
                <MatrixHeight>10534</MatrixHeight>
            </TileMatrix>
            <TileMatrix>
                <ows:Identifier>16</ows:Identifier>
                <ScaleDenominator>8530.918335622802</ScaleDenominator>
                <TopLeftCorner>-2.0037508342787E7 2.0037508342787E7</TopLeftCorner>
                <TileWidth>256</TileWidth>
                <TileHeight>256</TileHeight>
                <MatrixWidth>31829</MatrixWidth>
                <MatrixHeight>21068</MatrixHeight>
            </TileMatrix>
            <TileMatrix>
                <ows:Identifier>17</ows:Identifier>
                <ScaleDenominator>4265.459167338929</ScaleDenominator>
                <TopLeftCorner>-2.0037508342787E7 2.0037508342787E7</TopLeftCorner>
                <TileWidth>256</TileWidth>
                <TileHeight>256</TileHeight>
                <MatrixWidth>63658</MatrixWidth>
                <MatrixHeight>42136</MatrixHeight>
            </TileMatrix>
            <TileMatrix>
                <ows:Identifier>18</ows:Identifier>
                <ScaleDenominator>2132.729584141936</ScaleDenominator>
                <TopLeftCorner>-2.0037508342787E7 2.0037508342787E7</TopLeftCorner>
                <TileWidth>256</TileWidth>
                <TileHeight>256</TileHeight>
                <MatrixWidth>127316</MatrixWidth>
                <MatrixHeight>84272</MatrixHeight>
            </TileMatrix>
            <TileMatrix>
                <ows:Identifier>19</ows:Identifier>
                <ScaleDenominator>1066.3647915984968</ScaleDenominator>
                <TopLeftCorner>-2.0037508342787E7 2.0037508342787E7</TopLeftCorner>
                <TileWidth>256</TileWidth>
                <TileHeight>256</TileHeight>
                <MatrixWidth>254631</MatrixWidth>
                <MatrixHeight>168544</MatrixHeight>
            </TileMatrix>
        </TileMatrixSet>
        <TileMatrixSet>
            <ows:Title>GoogleMapsCompatible</ows:Title>
            <ows:Abstract>the wellknown 'GoogleMapsCompatible' tile matrix set defined by OGC WMTS
                specification</ows:Abstract>
            <ows:Identifier>GoogleMapsCompatible</ows:Identifier>
            <ows:SupportedCRS>urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG:6.18.3:3857</ows:SupportedCRS>
            <WellKnownScaleSet>urn:ogc:def:wkss:OGC:1.0:GoogleMapsCompatible</WellKnownScaleSet>
            <TileMatrix>
                <ows:Identifier>0</ows:Identifier>
                <ScaleDenominator>559082264.0287178</ScaleDenominator>
                <TopLeftCorner>-20037508.34278925 20037508.34278925</TopLeftCorner>
                <TileWidth>256</TileWidth>
                <TileHeight>256</TileHeight>
                <MatrixWidth>1</MatrixWidth>
                <MatrixHeight>1</MatrixHeight>
            </TileMatrix>
            <TileMatrix>
                <ows:Identifier>1</ows:Identifier>
                <ScaleDenominator>279541132.0143589</ScaleDenominator>
                <TopLeftCorner>-20037508.34278925 20037508.34278925</TopLeftCorner>
                <TileWidth>256</TileWidth>
                <TileHeight>256</TileHeight>
                <MatrixWidth>2</MatrixWidth>
                <MatrixHeight>2</MatrixHeight>
            </TileMatrix>
            <TileMatrix>
                <ows:Identifier>2</ows:Identifier>
                <ScaleDenominator>139770566.0071794</ScaleDenominator>
                <TopLeftCorner>-20037508.34278925 20037508.34278925</TopLeftCorner>
                <TileWidth>256</TileWidth>
                <TileHeight>256</TileHeight>
                <MatrixWidth>4</MatrixWidth>
                <MatrixHeight>4</MatrixHeight>
            </TileMatrix>
            <TileMatrix>
                <ows:Identifier>3</ows:Identifier>
                <ScaleDenominator>69885283.00358972</ScaleDenominator>
                <TopLeftCorner>-20037508.34278925 20037508.34278925</TopLeftCorner>
                <TileWidth>256</TileWidth>
                <TileHeight>256</TileHeight>
                <MatrixWidth>8</MatrixWidth>
                <MatrixHeight>8</MatrixHeight>
            </TileMatrix>
            <TileMatrix>
                <ows:Identifier>4</ows:Identifier>
                <ScaleDenominator>34942641.50179486</ScaleDenominator>
                <TopLeftCorner>-20037508.34278925 20037508.34278925</TopLeftCorner>
                <TileWidth>256</TileWidth>
                <TileHeight>256</TileHeight>
                <MatrixWidth>16</MatrixWidth>
                <MatrixHeight>16</MatrixHeight>
            </TileMatrix>
            <TileMatrix>
                <ows:Identifier>5</ows:Identifier>
                <ScaleDenominator>17471320.75089743</ScaleDenominator>
                <TopLeftCorner>-20037508.34278925 20037508.34278925</TopLeftCorner>
                <TileWidth>256</TileWidth>
                <TileHeight>256</TileHeight>
                <MatrixWidth>32</MatrixWidth>
                <MatrixHeight>32</MatrixHeight>
            </TileMatrix>
            <TileMatrix>
                <ows:Identifier>6</ows:Identifier>
                <ScaleDenominator>8735660.375448715</ScaleDenominator>
                <TopLeftCorner>-20037508.34278925 20037508.34278925</TopLeftCorner>
                <TileWidth>256</TileWidth>
                <TileHeight>256</TileHeight>
                <MatrixWidth>64</MatrixWidth>
                <MatrixHeight>64</MatrixHeight>
            </TileMatrix>
            <TileMatrix>
                <ows:Identifier>7</ows:Identifier>
                <ScaleDenominator>4367830.187724357</ScaleDenominator>
                <TopLeftCorner>-20037508.34278925 20037508.34278925</TopLeftCorner>
                <TileWidth>256</TileWidth>
                <TileHeight>256</TileHeight>
                <MatrixWidth>128</MatrixWidth>
                <MatrixHeight>128</MatrixHeight>
            </TileMatrix>
            <TileMatrix>
                <ows:Identifier>8</ows:Identifier>
                <ScaleDenominator>2183915.093862179</ScaleDenominator>
                <TopLeftCorner>-20037508.34278925 20037508.34278925</TopLeftCorner>
                <TileWidth>256</TileWidth>
                <TileHeight>256</TileHeight>
                <MatrixWidth>256</MatrixWidth>
                <MatrixHeight>256</MatrixHeight>
            </TileMatrix>
            <TileMatrix>
                <ows:Identifier>9</ows:Identifier>
                <ScaleDenominator>1091957.546931089</ScaleDenominator>
                <TopLeftCorner>-20037508.34278925 20037508.34278925</TopLeftCorner>
                <TileWidth>256</TileWidth>
                <TileHeight>256</TileHeight>
                <MatrixWidth>512</MatrixWidth>
                <MatrixHeight>512</MatrixHeight>
            </TileMatrix>
            <TileMatrix>
                <ows:Identifier>10</ows:Identifier>
                <ScaleDenominator>545978.7734655447</ScaleDenominator>
                <TopLeftCorner>-20037508.34278925 20037508.34278925</TopLeftCorner>
                <TileWidth>256</TileWidth>
                <TileHeight>256</TileHeight>
                <MatrixWidth>1024</MatrixWidth>
                <MatrixHeight>1024</MatrixHeight>
            </TileMatrix>
            <TileMatrix>
                <ows:Identifier>11</ows:Identifier>
                <ScaleDenominator>272989.3867327723</ScaleDenominator>
                <TopLeftCorner>-20037508.34278925 20037508.34278925</TopLeftCorner>
                <TileWidth>256</TileWidth>
                <TileHeight>256</TileHeight>
                <MatrixWidth>2048</MatrixWidth>
                <MatrixHeight>2048</MatrixHeight>
            </TileMatrix>
            <TileMatrix>
                <ows:Identifier>12</ows:Identifier>
                <ScaleDenominator>136494.6933663862</ScaleDenominator>
                <TopLeftCorner>-20037508.34278925 20037508.34278925</TopLeftCorner>
                <TileWidth>256</TileWidth>
                <TileHeight>256</TileHeight>
                <MatrixWidth>4096</MatrixWidth>
                <MatrixHeight>4096</MatrixHeight>
            </TileMatrix>
            <TileMatrix>
                <ows:Identifier>13</ows:Identifier>
                <ScaleDenominator>68247.34668319309</ScaleDenominator>
                <TopLeftCorner>-20037508.34278925 20037508.34278925</TopLeftCorner>
                <TileWidth>256</TileWidth>
                <TileHeight>256</TileHeight>
                <MatrixWidth>8192</MatrixWidth>
                <MatrixHeight>8192</MatrixHeight>
            </TileMatrix>
            <TileMatrix>
                <ows:Identifier>14</ows:Identifier>
                <ScaleDenominator>34123.67334159654</ScaleDenominator>
                <TopLeftCorner>-20037508.34278925 20037508.34278925</TopLeftCorner>
                <TileWidth>256</TileWidth>
                <TileHeight>256</TileHeight>
                <MatrixWidth>16384</MatrixWidth>
                <MatrixHeight>16384</MatrixHeight>
            </TileMatrix>
            <TileMatrix>
                <ows:Identifier>15</ows:Identifier>
                <ScaleDenominator>17061.83667079827</ScaleDenominator>
                <TopLeftCorner>-20037508.34278925 20037508.34278925</TopLeftCorner>
                <TileWidth>256</TileWidth>
                <TileHeight>256</TileHeight>
                <MatrixWidth>32768</MatrixWidth>
                <MatrixHeight>32768</MatrixHeight>
            </TileMatrix>
            <TileMatrix>
                <ows:Identifier>16</ows:Identifier>
                <ScaleDenominator>8530.918335399136</ScaleDenominator>
                <TopLeftCorner>-20037508.34278925 20037508.34278925</TopLeftCorner>
                <TileWidth>256</TileWidth>
                <TileHeight>256</TileHeight>
                <MatrixWidth>65536</MatrixWidth>
                <MatrixHeight>65536</MatrixHeight>
            </TileMatrix>
            <TileMatrix>
                <ows:Identifier>17</ows:Identifier>
                <ScaleDenominator>4265.459167699568</ScaleDenominator>
                <TopLeftCorner>-20037508.34278925 20037508.34278925</TopLeftCorner>
                <TileWidth>256</TileWidth>
                <TileHeight>256</TileHeight>
                <MatrixWidth>131072</MatrixWidth>
                <MatrixHeight>131072</MatrixHeight>
            </TileMatrix>
            <TileMatrix>
                <ows:Identifier>18</ows:Identifier>
                <ScaleDenominator>2132.729583849784</ScaleDenominator>
                <TopLeftCorner>-20037508.34278925 20037508.34278925</TopLeftCorner>
                <TileWidth>256</TileWidth>
                <TileHeight>256</TileHeight>
                <MatrixWidth>262144</MatrixWidth>
                <MatrixHeight>262144</MatrixHeight>
            </TileMatrix>
        </TileMatrixSet>
    </Contents>
    <ServiceMetadataURL
        xlink:href="http://esri-server/arcgis/rest/services/Basemaps/Locate/MapServer/WMTS/1.0.0/WMTSCapabilities.xml"
    />
</Capabilities>
```

Comment: Does the link work in your browser?

Comment: Hi Ian, If i put the tile request URL in a browser i get a message 'Error occurred while processing request, Type: Status Report, Description: http.400' from ArcGIS. I am wondering if there is an incompatibility between the tile request from GeoServer and ArcGIS WMTS? Thanks Adam

Comment: Looks like the server is broken or lied in its getcapabilities file. Can you add the relevant part of the getcapabilities file to the question

Comment: Hi Ian, Can you let me know exactly which fields you are interested in? Thanks

Comment: This sample WMTS on the net from ArcGIS produces the same error as on my system, thanks http://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/Toronto/ImageServer/WMTS/1.0.0/WMTSCapabilities.xml

Comment: Hi Ian, I have managed to insert the whole getcapabilities fle in the question, I am offline now for a while as travelling. thanks Adam.

Comment: Note HTTP 400 is Bad request, not, page not found ~ Just wondering whether you should use `GetTile` rather than `getTile` as parameter values are s.s. case sensitive.  Also note the capabilities response has `<Format>image/jpgpng</Format>` which seems odd and you are asking for `format=image%2Fpng&`

Comment: I've raised a bug (https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/browse/GEOT-6017) about this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were hitting a [bug](https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/browse/GEOT-6017) in the underlying GeoTools library where I had made the assumption that not naming the style would use the default, in the same way as a WMS getMap request works. This is how GeoServer interprets the specification too so all my tests passed.

I have now [fixed](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/pull/1891) this bug since there is arguably a way to read the WMTS specification to say that there must be a name in the style parameter of a KVP request and that is obviously the way that ESRI's engineers read it. Keep any eye on that PR and when it is merged the next GeoServer master nightly build should pick up the fix and you can test it.

Comment: Hi, Many thanks for looking into this. I have downloaded the nightly build from 13th May and tested it with the online ArcGIS sample WMTS source (http://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/Toronto/ImageServer/WMTS/1.0.0/WMTSCapabilities.xml) which was showing the same error as my system and it seems to have fixed it. It will be a couple of days before i can test it on my system as i don't have access to it from home but will report back, thanks again, Adam

Comment: Hi Ian, Yes the fix has worked on my system and i can now cascade WMTS from ArcGIS. Many thanks for looking into this and providing a fix so quickly, it is much appreciated. Do you know when it will make it into the next GeoServer release? Thanks  Adam

Comment: see https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver/wiki/Release-Schedule, I'll look at back porting if I get achance over the weekend

Comment: Hi Ian, did this fix make it into 2.13.1 released on the 21st May, i could not find a reference for it?  Thanks

Comment: It went/will go into GeoTools 18.4, 19.2 and 20.0 (https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/browse/GEOT-6017) GeoServer 2.13.1 (http://blog.geoserver.org/2018/05/21/geoserver-2-13-1-released/) used GeoTools 19.1 so not yet.

Comment: OK, many thanks for this and all your help in solving my issue