# Download custom extent from WMTS

Tags: qgis, wms, fme-form, wmts, download

I need to download image patches from a WMTS server. However, WMTS only allows to request tiles specified by row and column of the tile matrix.

What I need to achieve is some kind of "WMS-like" query which lets me specify a spatial bounding box. I am aware that there is no server-side processing on WMTS servers. Therefore I am looking for a workaround.

I achieve the desired result by adding the WMTS as a layer to QGIS and use the "Save as..." function of the layer, which lets me specify the spatial extent and resolution. Since I need to do this for ten-thousands of image patches I need to find a way to automate this. Unfortunately, FME does not have a reader for WMTS.

Any ideas?

Comment: GDAL has a WMTS driver http://gdal.org/frmt_wmts.html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could [cascade](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/data/cascaded/wmts.html) the WMTS service through a local GeoServer install and make WMS requests to the local server.

Comment: This is a great idea! Setting it up is a matter of minutes. However, the WMS only gives me images of red markings and "Failed Tile_xx_xx" written on them.

Comment: could be related to https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/282403/cascading-wtms-from-arcgis-server-in-geoserver I'm looking for a fix now

Comment: bug should be fixed in next nightly master GeoServer please test

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have another solution, but you mentioned FME so I'll confirm that WMTS is not supported as yet. It is under consideration (PR#44908) so if you ever want to check on its status, just contact the support team and quote that reference number.